# Missing entire order review block

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

I am missing the entire order review and submit order block (step 6 at checkout).
The section is just a blank empty DIV with nothing in it.

I am using a theme, but I never seen this problem with any theme so far.

The DIV is just empty:

```
<div class="order-review" id="checkout-review-load"></div>
```

Can someone help me out on this problem?
Its v 1.7.0.0 with "Madame Modern" theme.

Theme hints:

http://shrani.si/f/1k/sP/4dQZuDof/snapz-pro-xscreensnapz00.jpg

Google developer outputs on previous action:

- http://shrani.si/f/2D/ol/v0Ekrdc/snapz-pro-xscreensnapz00.jpg
- http://shrani.si/f/2o/sO/VCJEJdC/snapz-pro-xscreensnapz00.jpg

After enabling logging i get a system.log with:

```
2013-10-23T10:04:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument  in /home/ninocka/domains/*/public_html/lib/Zend/Json.php on line 146
2013-10-23T10:04:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument  in /home/ninocka/domains/*/public_html/lib/Zend/Json.php on line 146
2013-10-23T10:04:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument  in /home/ninocka/domains/*/public_html/lib/Zend/Json.php on line 146
```

Comment: Can you turn on template hints in the backend to check from where it's actually trying to load the template file. Optionally, if you have 3th party extensions installed that might influence this list them as well

Comment: I havent install any extensions so far. What do you mean by template hints?

Comment: Under `System > Configuration` switch the scope to the `website` you are debugging. Then go to `developer > Debug` and set `Template Path Hints` to *yes*

Comment: yea I found that, but never used it, so I am not sure what to expect now :)

Comment: Well make sure that if it's a live shop you fill out your IP. Also turn of caching. Then turn this on and you will see the template paths in the frontend so you know what files are being used for what blocks. It's a great feature

Comment: wow its really great.. see the image i attached.

Comment: btw my shop is in maintenance mode I added my ip in index.php so I can access it... could this be the case? (i dont think so...)

Comment: Hm it uses the default. Can you check if there are any issues/errors/warnings in the var/log/system.log or error.log?

Comment: hm not sure if that's the issue but it could be. When going from payment to review use the chrome webdeveloper toolbar network tab to see what output savePayment gives (firefox probably has something like that as well)

Comment: see the updated question ... could there be a problem with encoding?

Comment: Check out this post on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741894/zend-jsonencode-messing-up-why/1742111#1742111

Comment: perhaps i will fix all the "special" characters in the translation CSV files first ... perhaps then the encoding function wont have a problem... but I am still not sure if this error is related to the problem.

Comment: Actually the JSON contains the html for the review step. Since the 'html' key only contains `null` it won't output this step correctly

Comment: ok. I have to go trough tons of translations here, since the official CSVs downloaded from Magento are CRAP. I usualy just use my own translate.csv but with the Mage files comes tons of weird characters. Will let you know later (probably tonight) It this works be sure to write answer so you can gain some rep. Best regards to netherlands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably in the `savePayment` method in the `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController` class where the HTML output for the review step is added to the JSON.

As you've stated the log shows a JSON error so I did a quick search on that found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741894/zend-jsonencode-messing-up-why/1742111#1742111) on SO that might explain the issue if you indeed are running an older version of PHP. Also your screenshots of the JSON output show an empty 'html' key in the JSON so that confirms something goes wrong with adding the html to the output.

Since you're building the shop in the Polish language it might be a weird character that is tripping up the HTML output. To check if this is correct a suggestion might be to revert back to the base english language and see if the error still occurs. If not then the issue might be in one of your translation files.

Comment: true. I had to go over all CSV filesfor si_SL locale and fix the weird characters (û=ž,≈æ=ž,é=Ž,ä=Š,ö=š,≈°=š,Ë=č,»=Č...) and save all the files in UTF-8 encoding. The problem went away. Thank you again Sander Mangel. Blessed!